# i am trying to create a register activity in android at time of execution the control goes into register method and after that control stops

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a register activity in android my control goes to registration method but and also I have done validation when I click on signUp it directly goes to the next activity without validating or registering
when I start the application
and come to signup activity it works properly 
also, the log messages are printing
but after the register method called nothing is working
Control goes to Register() method after that it does not work 
it directly opens the next activity
validations and also firebase create method is not accessible
here is the code I have written

```
    package com.ap.pran;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.Patterns;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener; 
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

    public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextMobileNo, editTextVehicleNo, editTextName;
    private static final String TAG = " ANAND MESSAGE";
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        Log.i(TAG, "in onCreate1");
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        editTextMobileNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMobileNo);
        editTextVehicleNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVehicleNo);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.SignIn).setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    private void registerUser() {
        Log.i(TAG, "In register method");
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required !!!");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {

            editTextPassword.setError("Password is required !!!");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (password.length()<6){
            editTextPassword.setError("Password length must be greater than 6");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"User Registred !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "User Registration Failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });




    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonSignUp:
                Log.i(TAG, "In case 1");
                registerUser();
                break;

            case R.id.SignIn:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                Log.i(TAG, "In case 2");
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remember that if you're using this method for the first time :

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"User Registred !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "User Registration Failed !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

it will work perfectly. But on registering any user it automatically signs in the user after completing the registration. So, there is no need to sign in again if registered successfully.
To make the new registration again you must log out the previous registered user in that app.

Note :

I'll also recommend you to use `Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in else statement as follows if registration fails:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(SignUp.this,"User Registred !!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                  Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

It will help to identify the reason of registration failure.